# PHP floatval, intval, substr not returning values correctly

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, substring

```
<?php
$Content = "0968571.0569875198.740756475689345823327000000000465735639486589346538946589236587";
echo floatval(substr($Content, 5, 14))."<br />";
echo floatval(substr($Content, 16, 25))."<br />";
echo substr($Content, 27, 37)."<br />";
?>
```

Why is this code returning

```
71.0569875198
98.740756475689
5689345823327000000000465735639486589
```

when it should return

```
71.056987
98.740756
5689345823
```

This is just a test data!

Comment: This shouldn't even run, I guess you're missing quotes around your number in this example.

Comment: lol...that was a typo! sorry didn't notice that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

substr( string $string , int $start [, int **$length** ] )

I think you're imagining it's startIndex and endIndex like the java version of substring.

You probably mean:

```
echo floatval(substr($Content, 5, 14 - 5))."<br />";
echo floatval(substr($Content, 16, 25 - 16))."<br />";
echo substr($Content, 27, 37 -27)."<br />";
```

Comment: yep! was kinda confused! this fixed it! thanks! I'm such a stupid!